# React constant infinite loop carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been looking for 2 days now to find a carousel that is capable of an infinite loop where it moves 1 div top to bottom in a loop. All I can find is carousels that break for a few seconds then next slide. I am looking for something that is constantly moving and capable of top to bottom as well as side to side. I cant seem to find anything or actually find how to do this. I have looked all over stack overflow and seems no one else has had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check these two libraries:
- https://react-slick.neostack.com/
- https://github.com/kidjp85/react-id-swiper#readme

Maybe they have solution for your problem.

Comment: Not really what I am looking for as it needs to be constant with no break in the moving like for example on this video https://youtu.be/AJxfsREWKOs